# Why does reference comparison work on a constant, but not on a variable with the same value?

Tags: rust

In the below code:

```
fn is_five(x: &i32) -> bool {
    x as *const i32 == &5 as *const i32
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    assert!(!is_five(&x));
    assert!(is_five(&5));
    assert!(!is_five(&6));
    println!("Success!");
}
```

Why `is_five(&x)` is false, while `is_five(&5)` is true?

---

[Code demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=dd44ace432ba539fb288f44aa87eb266) in Rust playground

Answer (score 1):

Writing `&5` to take the address of a constant could seem odd, but in this case the compiler decides to use a storage (in the constant section) and store this value in order to be able to take its address.
If this happens several times in the code, there is no need to have separate storages, all of them holding the same value.

If you try the following code [in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/avcxqE73v), you will see that the constant 5 is placed once in memory and the linker refers to it from several places.

In `is_five()`: `lea     rax, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]`

In `test2()`: `lea     rdi, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]`

Thus `&5` refers to the same address, but `&x`, which is a local variable, refers to another storage for `x` initialised with the same value (`5`).

In `test1()`: `lea     rdi, [rsp + 4]`

```rust
pub fn is_five(x: &i32) -> bool {
    x as *const i32 == &5 as *const i32
}

pub fn test1() -> bool {
    let x = 5;
    is_five(&x)
}

pub fn test2() -> bool {
    is_five(&5)
}
```

If distinction between reference and pointer comparisons is not clear, [this documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.eq.html) can help.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=928a7843a3aa33977d7f90e9c5d1ad4d
why does comparing different String instances, or even references to different String instances, (that though have the same value) results equal?
Those are different pointers to even different locations (because the instances are different), aren't they?
Or should I ask this question as a separate question on StackOverflow instead?

Comment: @ИванПетрухин I think the answer to all of these questions is: the compiler puts things wherever it wants, and sometimes as an optimization it decides to reuse memory to save space if it detects that you're using the same value from multiple places.

Comment: @ИванПетрухин In Rust, comparisons on references (as in your second example with strings here) do not compare the references themselves but dereference first then compare the values. On the other hand, converting these references to pointers (as in your question) and then comparing these pointers, actually compares the addresses, not the values.

Comment: @prog-fh is also correct to be clear!

Comment: @prog-fh What's the difference between pointers and references and how to convert them? (The code I gave in the main question (with is_five) is not mine)

Comment: @ИванПетрухин you wrote `as *const i32` after references on `i32`; this where the conversion happens. May be should you read [some documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/pointer.html) if this is not clear?